# Como inserir uma nova chave associado com um novo valor no final de um Array Multidimensional em PHP

Tags: php, array, loop

Possuo um array multidimensional com a seguinte estrutura abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 1877
             [type_id] => 4
             [service_id] => 1100
         )

    [1] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2299
             [type_id] => 2
             [service_id] => 1148
         )
)
```

<sup>[Imagem da array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLQY7.png)</sup>

Preciso inserir dinamicamente uma nova chave associada com um valor ao final de cada chave do array para ficar com a seguinte estrutura abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 1877
             [type_id] => 4
             [service_id] => 1100
             [nova_chave] => "Novo Valor"  <--- 
         )

    [1] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2299
             [type_id] => 2
             [service_id] => 1148
             [nova_chave] => "Novo Valor"  <--- 
         )
)
```

<sup>[Imagem da nova array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Md0.png)</sup>

Alguém poderia me ajudar a como implementar essa solução em PHP?

Comment: Para poder exemplificar de uma forma mais complete, pode me explicar de onde vem os dados para adicionar? Cada posição possuirá um valor diferente correto? Esses valores virão de um array como vai ser?

Comment: Vinicius Gabriel, isso mesmo os dados que serão inseridos na nova chave virão de um outro array.

Comment: Esse outro array de qual vem os dados tem qual estrutura? Tem algo que possa identificar qual valor deve ir para qual id por exemplo? Ou a ordem das posições no seu array associativo respeitam a mesma ordem dos valores que vem do array?

Comment: O outro array também possuirá um id, ex: [1] => (['id' => 2299, nova_chave => 'Novo Valor']), dai será preciso comparar os ID's e quando forem iguais pegar a 'nova_chave' => 'Novo Valor' e acrescentar na estrutura do 1º array, conseguiu entender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso. Vou deixar dois exemplos aqui:

**Primeiro exemplo:**

```
<?php

    $matriz = array(
        array("id" => 1877,"type_id" => 4,"service_id" => 1100),
        array("id" => 2299,"type_id" => 2,"service_id" => 1148)
    );

    $novo_1 = 1111; 

    //Inserindo o valor dinamicamente 
    for($i=0; $i < count($matriz); $i++)
    {
        $matriz[$i]["nova_chave"] =  $novo_1;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($matriz);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**Segundo Exemplo:**

```
<?php

    $matriz_2 = array(
        array("id" => 1877,"type_id" => 4,"service_id" => 1100),
        array("id" => 2299,"type_id" => 2,"service_id" => 1148)
    );  

    $novo_2 = ["nova_chave_2" => 2222];  

    //Inserindo a chave e o valor dinamicamente
    for($i=0; $i < count($matriz_2); $i++)
    {
        foreach($novo_2 as $key => $value)
        {
            $matriz_2[$i][$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($matriz_2);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mais facil que se imagina. É só usar + com a nova chave e valor com o $arrayAssoc.

Para inserir a nova chave no inicio:

`foreach ($arrayAssoc $key => $value) {
    $arrayAssoc[$key] = array('nova_chave'=> "novo_valor") + $arrayAssoc[$key];
}`

Para inserir a nova chave no final:

`foreach ($arrayAssoc $key => $value) {
    $arrayAssoc[$key] = $arrayAssoc[$key]+ array('nova_chave'=> "novo_valor");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Então, no caso que exemplificou o 'X' da questão é o fato de que no array de valores não há um nome fixo para a nova chave que será adicionada ao seu array inicial.

Essa seria uma solução:

```
foreach ($arrayAssociativo as $arr)
{
  foreach ($arrayValores as $arrValor)
  {
    if ($arr['id'] === $arrValor['id'])
    {
      $arr = array_merge($arr, $arrValor);
    }
  }
}
```

Nesse caso para cada posição do seu array associativo inicial é verificado todas as posições do seu array de valores. Caso alguma posição possua o mesmo ID os array são *mergeados* com o [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php).

Considerando na estrutura que você informou de que o array de valores sempre possuirá apenas duas chaves (id e a nova chave a ser adicionada), **a chave id se manterá e a nova chave será adicionada junto ao seu valor**.

Comment: Vinicius Gabriel essa solução proposta não era o que eu esperava, ficou diferente do que eu preciso, o array merge está unindo um array com o outro e não é isso que eu preciso, o que eu preciso é pegar apenas uma chave com o seu valor do segundo array e adicionar no primeiro array. :(

Comment: @JorgitodaSilvaPaiva então, nesse seu cenário, o array_merge vai fazer exatamente isso. Como seu array de valores só tem 2 chaves ('id' , 'chave_nova') ele vai adicionar a chave nova no primeiro array.

Como essa sua chave nova possui nomes variados, acredito que essa seria a solução mais simplificada na verdade, há outras formas mas o código fica um pouco mais extenso.

Comment: Por acaso você testou em não retornou o resultado esperado? Se puder informar aqui como acabou ficando, talvez eu possa ser errado em alguma quesito ali, dai já verifico e corrijo.